# Symfony2.2 can't run composer update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Since this morning I can't update my vendor packages in Symfony. I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Composer\Script\PackageEvent' not found in phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Script/EventDispatcher.php on line 78
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar:0
PHP   2. require() /var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar:15
PHP   3. Composer\Console\Application->run() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
PHP   5. Composer\Console\Application->doRun() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:119
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:212
PHP   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:882
PHP   9. Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
PHP  10. Composer\Installer->run() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:103
PHP  11. Composer\Installer->doInstall() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:208
PHP  12. Composer\Script\EventDispatcher->dispatchPackageEvent() phar:///var/bean/deploy/qa/2013-06-03/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:476
```

Anyone knows what could've caused this? It get's resolved if I switch my symfony to the latest version of 2.3, but I don't want to do that at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was APC opcode cache. I manually downloaded composer using command line by running:

> php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"

and while running that command, it notified me that:

```
The apc.enable_cli setting is incorrect.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
    apc.enable_cli = Off
```

So I turned it off and it's all working great.